# Completion in Org Mode differs slightly from what manual promises

Tags: org-mode, completion

I don't seem to be getting the completion behavior in Org Mode that the [manual says](https://orgmode.org/manual/Completion.html) I should get (or see `(info "(org)Completion")`). It says that `M-<TAB>` will offer various Org specific completions in certain locations, for example:

• At the beginning of a headline, complete `TODO` keywords.

• After `\`, complete TeX symbols supported by the exporter.

• After `*`, complete headlines in the current buffer.

And a few other things like that. And the manual then says that *"When point is anywhere else, complete dictionary words using Ispell."*

OK, so here is what I actually get:

- Prior to Org 9.2 (I tried with 9.1.9), both `M-<TAB>` and `C-M-i` call `pcomplete` which does everything the manual says except the last thing about using Ispell!
- On Org 9.2, `M-<TAB>` calls `pcomplete` which does everything the manual says except the last thing about Ispell; and `C-M-i` calls `ispell-complete-word` that, obviously, just does the Ispell thing.

Weirdly, I cannot figure out where `C-M-i` is being bound to `ispell-complete-word` (according to `C-h k` the binding is in `org-mode-map`, but the Org Mode source files don't seem to mention `ispell-complete-word` at all).

I've tested both Org 9.1.9 and Org 9.2 starting from `emacs -Q`, so this shouldn't be a problem with my configuration.

1. Is the manual just wrong about the behavior of completion? In which case I should file a bug, I guess.
2. The behavior described in the manual sounds pretty sweet! How do I get it? That is, a single keybinding to do the Org specific completions *and* if none are possible, then use Ispell.
3. Just out of curiosity: how the hell is Org Mode 9.2 binding `C-M-i` to `ispell-complete-word` and how could I have discovered where it happens?

Comment: I was also fighting the same problem yesterday. It used to work for me, but no longer does. I think `C-M-i` is a global `ispell` binding (but I could not find where this is done either), which used to be overridden by the local map in Org mode. Curiously, in the Org mode source for v 9.2, you will find the binding for  `M-<TAB>` and `ESC <TAB>`, but not for `C-M-i`. For the time being, I bound it manually to `pcomplete` in org-mode-map and it seems to work (except for calling `ispell` "anywhere else").

Comment: Regarding, 3. `C-M-i` is bound to `ispell-complete-word` in the `text-mode-map` [here](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/textmodes/text-mode.el?id=7fcdabdcb03a47ec028a5821f6c3fc054d00b40d#n72). `outline-mode` is derived from `text-mode` and `org-mode` from `outline-mode`. As for 1, I think it's a bug, as you say. 2 would indeed be cool.

Comment: Thanks for figuring out 3, @aplaice! If you type `C-h k C-M-i` in an Org Mode buffer, the help that pops out says the binding is found in `org-mode-map`, which you've taught me to not to take too literally. :)

Comment: Actually, strictly speaking it *is* found in `org-mode-map`. :/ (If you inspect the variable `org-mode-map` you'll find it there...) Unfortunately, as you note, the help for `C-M-i` doesn't tell you that it was "inherited" from `text-mode` (I'm not sure if Emacs explicitly tracks this info); neither does the help for `org-mode-map` tell you that some of its binding were inherited from elsewhere. Only once you get to the help buffer for `org-mode` itself (linked to from `org-mode-map`) do you find out that `outline-mode` is `org-mode`'s parent mode (and ditto for `outline-mode` -> `text-mode`).

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure how the change of behaviour was introduced, but it should be fixed as of today:
https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/5fe9e6cbeaea12c020eeb495223ce359825121b8

Comment: Just to be clear: that change is not supposed to make completion behave as described in the manual, it is just intended to make completion behave as it did prior to 9.2, right?

Comment: @Omar That's what I take from the discussion in the Org mailing list (http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2019-01/msg00395.html), even though this question was linked there.

Comment: Can you add information on how to use these changes right now?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 I use this in my init file, it will be obsolete once a new version of org-plus-contrib is published (should be next week).
`(eval-after-load 'org
    '(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-TAB") #'pcomplete))`

Comment: @Omar Right, the fallback completion is not happening still, this should be fixed - or the documentation instead